# Using beautifulsoup to extract text in spans between two headers

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to scrape some text from a gig guide with listings by genre. I'm completely new to this, and I'm finding that I can return a list of genres and a full list of gig titles, but of course I only want to return gig titles associated with a particular genre (and then move to the next genre and pick up its gig-titles etc.) The source code for the gig guide is along these lines:

```
<h3>indie</h3>
    <span class="gig-title"><a href="/gig/BandA">BandA</a></span> 
    <span class="gig-title"><a href="/gig/BandB">BandB</a></span> 
    <span class="gig-title"><a href="/gig/BandC">BandC</a></span> 

<h3>jazz</h3>
    <span class="gig-title"><a href="/gig/BandD">BandD</a></span> 
    <span class="gig-title"><a href="/gig/BandE">BandE</a></span>
```

I can find all the genres and gig-titles with something like:

```
genres = soup.find_all("h3")
for genre in genres:
    titles = soup.find_all("span","gig-title")
    for title in titles:
        gig = title.a.string
```

But, I just want to return the text: "BandA", "BandB", "BandC" - that's the text between two h3 (genre) tags, before moving on to the next genre.

How I might approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `findall()` to find the header and the data at the same time.  And then just work with the piece of data that you need:

#### Code:

```
def get_genre_band(soup):
    genre = None
    for node in soup.findAll(['h3', 'span']):
        if node.name == 'h3':
            genre = node.text
        elif 'gig-title' in node.get('class', ''):
            yield genre, node.text
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = """
    <h3>indie</h3>
        <span class="gig-title"><a href="/gig/BandA">BandA</a></span> 
        <span class="gig-title"><a href="/gig/BandB">BandB</a></span> 
        <span class="gig-title"><a href="/gig/BandC">BandC</a></span> 

    <h3>jazz</h3>
        <span class="gig-title"><a href="/gig/BandD">BandD</a></span> 
        <span class="gig-title"><a href="/gig/BandE">BandE</a></span>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for g, b in get_genre_band(BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')):
    print("{} {}".format(g, b))
```

#### Results:

```
indie BandA
indie BandB
indie BandC
jazz BandD
jazz BandE
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm finding this works if I use the example data, but when I actually open the webpage to use the data there I get an error for the following line:
            elif 'gig-title' in node ['class']:
I can get rid this error if I edit ['class'] to either (['class']) or ('class'), but then nothing seems to happen.
(Note that I am using BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser') rather than 'lxml' - not sure if this could be part of the problem?)

Comment: Thanks for the update - this is awesome.  Now, to move on to the next problem!